# I get the error invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am quite new to programming,so I really need help. I need to wrtie a function which produce 2d arrays with random values. here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
float randArray(int row, int column);

int main()
{    
    int r = 10, c = 8;
    float fckMmd = randArray(r,c);
    ///printing the array:
     for (int row=0; row<r; row++){
        for (int column=0; column<c; column++){
            cout << fckMmd[row][column] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 
}


float randArray(int row, int column){
      srand(time(NULL));
      float *randArr;
      randArr = new int [row][column];
      for(int k=0; k<row; k++){
        for(int kk=0; kk<column; kk++){
            randArr[k][kk] = rand();
        }
      }
      return randArr;
}
```

But I get the error mentioned above. Where is the problem? help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randArr` is a `float *` but you try to allocate a 2d array in it. A 2d array is not the same thing as a pointer. Your function only returns 1 `float` as well. I suggest you use vectors (also so you don't leak memory). Furthermore you should only call `srand` ONCE, not every time, and be aware `rand()` returns an integer, not a floating point value.

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> randArray(int row, int column)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> randArr(row);
    for (auto& v : randArr)
    {
        v.resize(column);
    }

    for(int k=0; k<row; k++)
    {
        for(int kk=0; kk<column; kk++)
        {
            randArr[k][kk] = static_cast<float>(rand());
        }
    }

    return randArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
float *randArr;
```

declares a pointer to `float`. You then do

```
randArr = new int [row][column];
```

which allocates memory for a 2D array of `int`s (incompatible types, technically you allocate memory for a pointer to arrays of type `int[column]`), hence the error.

You're better using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, or, if you want a manually-managed dynamically allocated 2D array, use `float **randArr;` instead, and allocate

```
float** randArr;
randArr = new float* [rows];
for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    randArr[i] = new float[col];
```

or

```
float (*randArr)[col]; // pointer to array float[col]
randArr = new float[row][col];
```

Other issues: most of the time, `srand` must be used **only once** in the program. It is a good idea to call it in `main()` and not bury it into a function, since you may end up calling the function multiple times.

Last issue: if you want speed, you're better off using a single flat array (or `std::vector`) and map from 2D to 1D and vice versa, since your data will be guaranteed to be contiguous and you'll have very few cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `fckMmd` is only a float and not a pointer or array.